# Weights and balloons are in equilibrium on the figure

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

Inspired by this puzzle :

> Note that the weights and balloons are in equilibrium on the smaller figure. 
>  Move them to the larger figure and obtain equilibrium.

[image]

**I created my own version:**

> Put numbers -5 to 6, without 0 to the blue dots.
>   There are 2 solutions.

[image]

Comment: How this combines factor decomposition with other arithmetic makes for yet another of your puzzles, Jamal S, that I've enjoyed solving fresh without peeking at an already-posted solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer is:

> $A=-4 | B=5 | C=4 | D=-3 | E=1 | F=3 | G=-2  | H=-1 | I=2 | J=6 | K=-5$

The other answer is just simply changing values between $A,B,C,D$:

> $A=4 | B=-3 | C=-4 | D=5 | E=1 | F=3 | G=-2  | H=-1 | I=2 | J=6 | K=-5$

To find it, we need to consider all possible equations but starting with simple ones:

> First of all you need to start with $G$ and $H$, we know the relation $G=2H$. So the possible values will be $(-4,-2), (4,2), (2,1), (-2,-1)$.

Then let's think about E and F:

> $3F=E$, so only possible solutions will be $(-3,-1)$ and $(3,1)$.

Then after that, with a couple of trial and error considering:

1.

> $2(A+B+C+D+E+F+I)+4(G+H)=3J+4K$ We know from equation 2 that $A+B+C+D+E+F=6$ or $-6$. $J$ has to be even since the other numbers after parantheses has to be even!

2.

> $E+F=2(A+B+C+D)$ From this equation you know that $A+B+C+D=2$ or $-2$ since $E+F$ is $4$ or $-4$.

3.

> $3A+2B=C+2D$ from here, $3A+C$ has to be even number since $2B$ and $2D$ are even numbers. so Both $A$ and $C$ has to be even number. and $A+B+C+D=2/-2$ then both $B$ and $D$ has to be odd, there are a few amount of even number and it is guaranteed that at least one even number is used for $G$ and/or $H$ and $J$ is even number.

You get the answer above.

Comment: You can also get (2,6) for (E,F) from 3F=E.

Comment: @Lawrence to be honest, I did not consider that, since OP said there are 2 answers, probably it is not the case :) I will add that though.

Comment: First, you can also get (3,6) for (H,G). Second, "3A+C has to be even number [...] so Both A and C has to be even number." If A and C were both odd, 3A+C would be even.